# Run R script from Python

Tags: python, r, parsing, cmd, subprocess

I want to run an R-script from a Python script. The R-script is required for the projection of lat lon coordinates in a different coordinate system. I have considered two options to do this. In the first option I like to parse the lat and lon coordinates to the R-script which is shown below. Then finally I would like that the R-script returns the x and y back to the python script, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
project<-function(lat,lon){

library(sp)
library(rgdal)

xy <- cbind(x = lon, y = lat)
S <- SpatialPoints(xy)
proj4string(S) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
Snew <- spTransform(S, CRS("+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"))
x <- coordinates(Snew)[1]
y <- coordinates(Snew)[2]

return(x,y)
}
```

For my second option I've considered using the R-script at the bottom with the lat and lon already in it. I try to run this from python with subprocess.Popen('Rscript project.r', shell=True).wait() But this does not seem to work. It does not write an xy.txt file. If I run this from the cmd line, however, the R-script does the job. Who can help me out with one of these two options?

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

lat <- 52.29999924
lon <- 4.76999998

xy <- cbind(x = lon, y = lat)
S <- SpatialPoints(xy)
proj4string(S) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
Snew <- spTransform(S, CRS("+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"))
x <- coordinates(Snew)[1]
y <- coordinates(Snew)[2]

cat(x, file="xy.txt",sep="")
cat(y,file="xy.txt",append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you don't just use the Python GDAL binding? (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) Seems like it would be a lot easier.

Comment: If it's easier then I definitely would like to try that. However, I am not familiar with using gdal in python. Is there an example code of how to use gdal and project coordinates from one coordinate system into another?

Comment: I don't think it's much different from the R binding. If you just need to transform co-ordinates, you only need the proj4 bindings; it's as simple as this: `import pyproj; p1 = pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"); p2 = pyproj.Proj("+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"); pyproj.transform(p1, p2, 52.3, 4.77)` The lat/lon arguments can be lists, tuples, numpy arrays or scalars. See http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first solution -- get R to output the coordinates to the console (using print or cat or whatever it is in R), then capture that in Python (see here: [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output))

That will give you a string with teh lat/lon coords in it, you just have to Parse them out using the appropraite Python functions.

Comment: There is no need to manually parse the output of the R function, Rpy can do that for you much more easy.

Comment: Hi all, I'd like to thank you all for the very good answers. I think Rpy can do the job for me, however, Rpy does not seem to work with python version 2.5.4 and R version 2.14.2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me you are almost there, some remarks:

- `x <- coordinates(Snew)[1]` selects the first item, use `x <- coordinates(Snew)[,1]` to get the entire vector. This assumes that you pass vectors of `lat` and `lon`, and not single values. There is no reason here why we should not allow passing vectors of `lat` `lon`.
- `return(x,y)` is not valid, R does not support returning multiple objects. In stead, just `return(cbind(x,y))`.
- Inside a function I would use `require`.

In regard to running the code from Python, I'd have a look at [Rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/). This allows you to call R code from within Python. Rpy does a lot of the hard work of passing R objects back and forth for you, so this is a nice option in this case.

The approach I would take in Rpy is to put `project` in a `.R` file, `source` that file, and call `project`.

Comment: `library` will also not reload a loaded package.